# Running Google Closure Test Suite Headlessly

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, continuous-integration, google-closure-library

I am using Google Closure tools extensively, and would like to be able to run my unit tests without launching a browser, both for speed purposes and also for easier integration with continuos integration tools like Hudson. Any advice? Could this be done with server side javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realized that the Google Closure Testing framework is not really ment to be run without a DOM in place, hence, that it was not a good idea to run these tests on the server side. Instead, I will use selenium and the frameworks' multiple test runner to run the tests in a CI environment.

Comment: I ended up going this route as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Gradually, I switch to Jstestdriver, and it works great.